# Fedora 26: dnf update not working behind proxy - failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'

Tags: fedora, proxy, dnf

On Fedora 26 when I do `sudo dnf -v update` I get the error

```
>     Loaded plugins: builddep, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache,
> needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repograph, repomanage,
> reposync, system-upgrade
>     DNF version: 2.6.3
>     cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
>     Cannot download 'http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/26/x86_64/':
> Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All
> mirrors were tried.
>     Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates'
```

I configured both my system-wide proxy and the proxy in dnf.conf.  Other connections such as the browser work with this proxy.  The proxy requires authentication - I have set the needed values in dnf.conf `proxy_username` and `proxy_password`.

I also have a .bashrc which sets `http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port/`.  Then if I run `curl http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/26/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml`, it fails with HTTP 407.  It works if I add `--proxy-ntlm`.  According to the [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1219199), `dnf` has been already patched so that it permits NTLM when calling into `libcurl`.

However, `yum` additionally used to disable Kerberos/"negotiate" authentication, because in some cases that would be the first option offered, and it would fail where NTLM would work.  A patch was offered for this second, but the bug was closed after resolving only the first problem...

How can I get `dnf update` to work?

Comment: I know it's annoying, but could you excerpt a greater amount of the output please, to show that this is the only error `dnf` gives.  IIRC I've had to resorted to `wireshark` to debug some cases.  If you can do that, and show the HTTP request which fails, that might provide useful information.

Comment: That is the only message printed in the terminal. How can I retrieve more relevant logs?

Comment: It's also possible you would benefit from editing all the repos to use `baseurl` (commented by default) and comment out all the `metalink=` magic.  That's useful specifically if dnf is retrying with lots of different repos and you want it to be less noisy.  It's also what you want if you want your proxy to cache the updates for sharing between computers.

Comment: I tried commenting out metalink and using baseurl in /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora-updates.repo. Still the same error message.

Comment: If that is literally the only message printed, you can illustrate that by copying from your terminal and including the dnf command as well as the output.  (When I want to emphasize that there is no further output, I also include the following shell prompt).  I'm prodding you because I don't remember dnf being quite that terse.  My memory might be wrong, and as I say I'm not expecting it to be that much more helpful, but it would show the problem you're having more clearly to other people.

Comment: I updated the output using the verbose flag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65175/discussion-between-barq-and-sourcejedi).

Comment: Does this work today? There was a DNS-related outage yesterday; perhaps your working systems simply had the information cached, or were using different DNS servers.

Comment: No, I heard about the DNS problem, but my issue has existed before, during and after this outage. It is still not working today.

Comment: Another 13 hours later and it is still not working @mattdm

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution. The problem is this bug,  which is still not fixed: 
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1387622

I had to edit /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf/repo.py and change the following:

```
-        h.setopt(librepo.LRO_PROXYAUTH, True)
+        h.setopt(librepo.LRO_PROXYAUTHMETHODS, 8)
```

Comment: This was finally fixed in a newer version of dnf. The lines do not need to be changed manually after every update any longer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1219199), `dnf` has been already patched so that it permits NTLM when calling into `libcurl`.

However, `yum` additionally used to disable Kerberos/"negotiate" authentication, because in some cases that would be the first option offered, and it would fail where NTLM would work.  A patch was offered for this second issue, but the bug was closed after resolving only the first problem...  Considering NTLM works for you, it is most likely this is your problem.  (You can look at the bug to see more details about what the HTTP reply headers would look like in this situation, e.g. if you captured them with Wireshark).

In this case, it seems the only currently available solution is to set up a proxy on your local computer, which converts Basic authentication to NTLM auth, or something like that.  See [NTLM-APS](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

in dnf.conf add

```
proxy=http://cisco-wsa.internal.net:3128
proxy_username=myusername
proxy_password=VeryStrongPassword
```